# how to store yield request responses on scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Hi I am new to python and scrapy. So this is going to be a noob question. I tried searching as well but couldn't find anything that directly answers my question.
I am trying to go through the below webpages of countries and store their population in an array and then print them at once. The code below as you can see, prints every time there is a request made. How could I instead print later in bulk with an array of the results? Thanks

```
class CrawlerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wikiCrawler'
    #allowed_domains = ['web']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states']
    #counter = 1
    global i
    i = {}
    global list
    list = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 1
        pass

    def parse(self, response):

        for resultHref in response.xpath('//table[contains(@class, "wikitable")]//a[preceding-sibling::span[@class="flagicon"]]'):
            href = resultHref.xpath('./@href').extract_first()
            nameC = resultHref.xpath('./text()').extract_first()
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href), callback=self.parse_item, meta={'Country': nameC})

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.counter = self.counter + 1
        i['country'] = response.meta['Country']
        i['population'] = response.xpath('//tr[preceding-sibling::tr/th/a/text()="Population"]/td/text()').extract_first()
        yield i #this is where I would like to store the data instead of printing and then later print all together
```

Answer (score 0):

Created the i variable in the `parse_item` function instead of the class.
Tested this and it works although the xpath selector might need some improvement.

```
class CrawlerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wikiCrawler'
    #allowed_domains = ['web']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states']
    #counter = 1
    global list
    list = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 1
        pass

    def parse(self, response):

        for resultHref in response.xpath('//table[contains(@class, "wikitable")]//a[preceding-sibling::span[@class="flagicon"]]'):
            href = resultHref.xpath('./@href').extract_first()
            nameC = resultHref.xpath('./text()').extract_first()
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href), callback=self.parse_item, meta={'Country': nameC})

    def parse_item(self, response):
        i = {}
        self.counter = self.counter + 1
        i['country'] = response.meta['Country']
        i['population'] = response.xpath('//tr[preceding-sibling::tr/th/a/text()="Population"]/td/text()').extract_first()
        yield i #this is where I would like to store the data instead of printing and then later print all together
```

Comment: hi. Sorry this is not what I was after. I have created a separate question. Could you help with that one please? Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610655/python-how-to-add-response-from-scrapy-request-from-yield-into-an-array